# How to get coordinates to the viewDidLoad from the locationManager?

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocationmanager

My question is: How can I get the locationManager coordinates to my viewDidLoad method to load my mapview with my previously checked position???

My locationManager lookin' like this (Strings for UIlabel):

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation { 
    if (wasFound) return;
    wasFound = YES;

CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [newLocation coordinate];


latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", loc.latitude];
longitude.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", loc.longitude];
```

}

And my viewDidLoad like this:

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate1;
theCoordinate1.latitude = 37.786996;
theCoordinate1.longitude = -122.419281;
```

So I want to insert my real coordinates to the latitude and longitude places!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make `CLLocationCoordinate2D loc` a property of whatever object your `didUpdateToLocation:` method is in.  If it's the same object as the `viewDidLoad` code, then just use it directly.  If it's in some other class, make a reference to that class available in your view controller and get the property that way.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` property and assign value to it.